# How can I turn off the blue clock display when debugging asynchronous code?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Often when debugging an piece of asynchronous code, it will give me this blue screen on my second monitor with a clock on it. This happens often after I pressed 'Continue' from a breakpoint but sometimes it also turns into a black screen.

Using the Windows button or dragging a window over it removes it but it is still rather annoying. Can I turn this off somewhere?

[image]

Comment: WinRT component executed using a Universal App Unit Test project.

Comment: provide more information about your application...

Comment: What kind of information?

Comment: This is just speculation but I think your component needs and winRT app and since you don't have one it automatically puts it on the clock app for the test to run, Again this is just speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can turn this off. I would assume a unit test project actually starts an app to be able to run the tests. Similar thing was the case with Silverlight unit tests - an app needs to be hosted somewhere to be able to run the code.

Perhaps you could use something like Stardock's ModernMix to make it possible to switch that app to run inside of a window to make it a bit less annoying to you.

Comment: This makes the most sense to me as well considering every unit test installs and uninstalls an instance of your app that it performs its tests with.